Strange relationship between two expectations related to die rolls
Let $X_n$ be the expected number of die rolls to get $n$ consecutive sixes. $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Let $Y_n$ be the expected number of die rolls to get any number $n$ times consecutively.
$X_n$ = $\frac{6^{n+1} - 6}{5}$ and $Y_n = \frac{6^n - 1}{5}$ which is shown here.
Some $X_i$ and $Y_i$ values:
$X_0 = 0, X_1 = 6, X_2 = 42, X_3 = 258 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$
$Y_1 = 1, Y_2 = 7, Y_3 = 43, Y_4 = 259$
Two observations:

$X_n = 6 \cdot Y_n; \quad$ This is very intuitive and the combinatorial argument for it is discussed here
$\boxed{Y_{n+1} = X_n + 1}$

I am unable to understand why the second relationship exists between the two. It is algebraically evident and can be easily proven to be true for any $n ≥ 0$. What I want to know is:
Does there exist a combinatorial argument for the second relationship?

Let $X_n^{[i]}$ with $i \in \{1, \dots, 6\}$ be a random variable denoting the number of rolls to see $n$ consecutive $i$'s and $Y_{n + 1}$ be the random variable representing the number of rolls required to see any number $n + 1$ consecutive times.
$$Y_{n + 1} = \sum_{i = 1}^6 \mathbf{1}_{[i]} \left( X_n^{[i]} + 1 \right)$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{[i]}$ is the indicator variable that $i$ is the number that appears $n + 1$ times. Note $\mathbf{1}_{[i]} \perp X_n^{[i]}$ so in expectation
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[ Y_{n + 1} \right] &= 1 + \sum_{i=1}^6 \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{[i]} X_n^{[i]} \right] \\
&= 1 + \sum_{i=1}^6 \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{[i]} \right] \mathbb{E} \left[ X_n^{[i]} \right] \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=1}^6 \mathbb{E}\left[ X_n^{[i]} \right] \\
&= 1 + \mathbb{E}\left[ X_n^{[6]} \right]
\end{aligned}

This is a nice proof. However, I was looking for less probability theory and a more combinatorial proof for the relationship.

Yes. Substituting in using Equation 1, we are trying to show that $$Y_{n+1} = 6Y_n + 1$$ The derivation for this is essentially the same argument: we keep rolling $n$ in a row and then roll one more; if it is the right number we stop (total rolls: $Y_n+1$), otherwise we start over again using the new number as our first roll (total rolls: $Y_n+Y_{n+1}$). So $$Y_{n+1} = (1/6)(Y_n+1)+(5/6)(Y_{n+1}+Y_n) \\ \implies Y_{n+1}=(5/6)Y_{n+1} + Y_n + (1/6) \\ \implies Y_{n+1} = 6Y_n + 1$$

I did not ask for a substitution in the original equation followed by a subsequent combinatorial argument. You have essentially given the derivation for $Y_n$, which was already there in the link I attached.
